# Calculate row and col based on x y coordinate, TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, row, typeerror, raster, col

I am trying to get the row and column of an (x,y) point in a raster, while I cannot see why there was a TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable, from this code:

```
px = int((x - gt[0]) / gt[1])
```

I checked many problems similar to this, but still cannot figure out the reason for the error is in my case. Can anyone have a sharper eye to help me out?

```
path = 'E:\\sdnaia\\'
file = path+'dem.tif'
layer = gdal.Open(file)
gt =layer.GetGeoTransform()
bands = layer.RasterCount
#get raster value underneath given point
def Val_raster(x,y,layer,bands,gt):
    col=[]
    px = int((x - gt[0]) / gt[1])
    py =int((y - gt[3]) / gt[5])
    for j in range(bands):
        band = layer.GetRasterBand(j+1)
        data = band.ReadAsArray(px,py, 1, 1)
        col.append(data[0][0])
    return col
Val_raster(530472.8270679833,181203.99261843413,layer, bands,gt[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since x is a float you gave to the function Val_raster, but don't do any subscription on it, the problem is in the variable gt[0]. I don't know much about osgeo.gdal but a quick search in stackexchange [1] shows me that gdal.Open().GetGeoTransform() gives a 1-dimensional tuple: try printing out "gt" after initialising it with "gt = layer.GetGeoTransform()". Now since you pass gt[0] to Val_raster, which, since gt is a 1-D tuple, is a float (!), further subscription to this variable gt[0] = gt in the function Val_raster, like you do with gt[0], gt[2] etc., will give this error.

So try changing,

```
Val_raster(530472.8270679833,181203.99261843413,layer, bands,gt[0])
```

to,

```
Val_raster(530472.8270679833, 181203.99261843413, layer, bands, gt)
```

This will pass the tuple gt, not float gt[0] to the function!

---

Source [1]:

```
# Try reopening the dataset now and see if the geotransform has been set.
ds = gdal.Open('test_gt.tif')
print ds.GetGeoTransform()  #prints (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

[How do I change a raster's geotransform with GDAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726637/how-do-i-change-a-rasters-geotransform-with-gdal)

Comment: there is gt[1], already corrected, tried pass gt[1] to a variable, not working. The problem was introduced in the code: px = int((x - gt[0]) / gt[1]). I don't know how to fix it

Comment: try printing out gt directly after typing gt = layer.GetGeoTransform(), is it a 1D tuple? If so, declare your x and y's and try to do what you want to do without the function Val_raster, seems unncessary to me, and just unindent the code. I think this is the most I can help you with this, unless you share a link where I can download the .tif file.